# Using Microsoft Word with Onedrive

Tags: microsoft-word

Hi yesterday I opened a document saved in Onedive with Microsodt Word. I didn't bother to save or anything trusting the cloud feature to sync my file automatically with Onedrive. Today I opened the document and to my disappointment learned that the changes weren't saved. That taught me a lesson to always save a copy locally. My question is this: do Onedrive already do this? I mean if Onedrive is saving a copy locally by default? If not, can it be done saving a file both in One drive and locally simultaneously? And is using Word Online more safe or has it the same chances of losing your work? Thanks

Comment: Are you saying that you didn’t save the document in Microsoft Word?

Comment: When a Microsoft Word is opening a dcoument that in Onedrive it automatically sync and save it anytime you make a changes to the doc/

Comment: Its not always the case, you can check if the Autosave is On/Off at the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

If Word prompts you to save the document, you must save it.  If Autosave is turned on, you will not be prompted to save the document when you close it.